# KML file custom marker is not centered on ployline in google map which i have implemented in my angular 4 web application

Tags: angular

I have a kml file . I uploaded this file in my angular 4 web application and rendering it using agm-kml-layer by passing only url of file, but some custom icon is not in proper place.I am using this dependency "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2", in package.json. It is wroking fine on google earth.But in my project it is not working in my web application.

I also used hotspot tag for anchoring the icon.But it does't effect anymore

Here is code for render KML file on map.

`<agm-map [fitBounds]="latlngbounds" [latitude]="lat" [styles]="styles" [longitude]="lng"  [zoom]="mapZoom" [mapTypeId]="mapTypeID"   (mapReady)="mapReadyEvent($event)"><div *ngFor="let item of data" ><agm-kml-layer [url]="item.planFile"></agm-kml-layer></div></agm-map>`

Here is the KML file..without  tag.

https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/files/58167559e4b00e2f1a2c6e27/decbba0a-edd5-4006-a6f2-8fb997eca658.wallToWall.kml

I am getting no error . But icon is not centered on polyline. I wnat marker is to be centered of polyline.

I am providing a screenshot..

[In this image square marker should be in proper place (at the center of line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0nCL.png)

Comment: It is not clear what information your looking for. Please highlight or list the exact information you need so that the community can help you.

Comment: Also please post error messages or a screenshot so it's clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I have added a screenshot for what I am looking for.